# LREM a "big" string or SET/GET + LREM a "small" string

Tags: performance, redis, message-queue

I hope this doesn't come up as too much an open-ended question.

I'm using `RPOPLPUSH` to implement a [reliable queue](https://danielkokott.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/redis-reliable-queue-pattern/) and I'm trying to evaluate the tradeoffs between having the (possibly big) string value (e.g. JSON) directly in the list or by having only a "key" in the list and storing/retrieving the value using `SET`/`GET` (i.e. 2 extra calls), in this case, `LREM` is still O(N), but the string being smaller, should perform better.

Something I have not considered ?

Answer (score 1):

You should test it yourself.

That said, memory allocation/deallocation is faster than network so a large string will probably perform better.